# A question on limit points

Tags: real-analysis

I have a query regarding a question from Stephen Abbott's Understanding analysis.

Question: Is $\mathbb{Q}$ an open or closed set, or neither? Given a point is $\mathbb{Q}$ is there an $\epsilon$-neighborhood contained in $\mathbb{Q}$?

The solutions suggest $\mathbb{Q}$ is neither open nor closed - fine.

It also says that there is **no $\epsilon$-neighborhood contained in $\mathbb{Q}$**

I am not quite sure I understand the meaning of that last line.

For instance, isn't an $\epsilon$-neighbourhood centred at $0$ with $\epsilon = \frac{1}{10}$ contained in $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: Because both the rational and irrational numbers are dense in $\Bbb R$, any $\epsilon$-neighborhood around any point will contain an infinite number of both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An $\epsilon$ neighborhood around $0$ is the open interval $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$. All intervals contain both rational and irrational numbers.

Answer (score 1):

No. This neighbourhood contains the point $\frac{1}{10\sqrt{2}}$ which is not a rational.

Comment: This was something I overlooked. Just to be clear though, for an $\epsilon$-neighbourhood to exist in some set, it cannot have any gaps in it?

Comment: @elbarto Not quite, $(0,1) \cup (2,3)$ is open (so every point has an $\epsilon$-neighbourhood around it inside it), but has a gap between 1 and 2. But if a point has an $\epsilon$-neighbourhood around it within that set, there is no gap "close to " $x$.

Comment: I don't quite understand "close to x". Does an epsilon neighbourhood exist at the point 1 or the point 2 in this set?

Comment: No, not at 1 or 2, as these balls there stick out. But 1,2 are not in the set.

Comment: Okay, so given a set $[0,1)$, it's true there is no epsilon-neighborhood at the point $0$ ? (obviously also none at $1$ but I was adressing the point in your comment where you said $1$ and $2$ were not in the set).

Comment: Indeed. Not in the real numbers.

Comment: Thanks! This clears everything up for me.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, open or closed in *what* ? Because it's both open and closed in itself. ;-) This is general, any topological space $X$ is open and closed in itself, for open sets are stable by intersection, the empty intersection (which is therefore open) gives the empty set, which is open, so that its complement $X$ is closed in $X$, and the empty union gives the whole set $X$, which is open in $X$.

I guess you meant in $\mathbf{R}$. Then it is not closed because $\overline{\mathbf{Q}} = \mathbf{R} \not= \mathbf{Q}$ as $\sqrt{2}\not\in\mathbf{Q}$. And it is not open because then $0$ would be in its interior, so that you could find a small open ball $B(0,\varepsilon)$ contained in $\mathbf{Q}$, but this small ball will necessarily meet irrational numbers (for $\frac{\pi}{2^n}$ for $n\in\mathbf{N}$ big enough would be in it) leading to a contradiction.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the part where you said $\mathbb{Q}$ is open and closed in itself? If there is not existence of an $\epsilon$-neighborhood in $\mathbb{Q}$ how can it ever be open? I can see that in itself - it is closed, because it contains the limit point $0 \in \mathbb{Q}$



Edit: I read the rest of your comment - makes sense, when you say open in itself, the $\epsilon$-neighborhood exists since we are only considering the set of $\mathbb{Q}$ so whilst $\mathbb{I}$ may be dense in $\mathbb{Q}$ we do not have to consider these, since we are only dealing with $\mathbb{Q}$ - correct?

Comment: You can define your space to be $\mathbb{Q}$ **only**, i.e that irrational numbers do not exist in a sense. The interval $(0,1)$ is the set of rational numbers between 0 and 1. It is an open set. The sequence $1/2, 3/4, 7/8,... $ converges to 1, so the set is not closed since it does not include 1. A sequence in $(0,1)$ which "converges" to an irrational will be considered to "not converge". As you go on in your studies, you'll learn that you can define which sets are "open" in many ways. However, for a first real analysis course, you are usually restricted to the real number line continuum.

Comment: @elbarto Just edited my answer.

Comment: Not to start an extended discussion, but consider the one point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$: $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$. With an appropriately defined metric (say, the distance between $n$ and $n+1$ decreases fast enough as $n$ grows), the sequence $1,2,3,...$ **converges** to $\infty$, and the interval $[0,\infty)$ is no longer closed! The closed interval is now $[0,\infty]$. Concluding, there are many different constructions of "open/closed", "converge/diverge", etc. I find it both beautiful and exciting!